# ClassNotFoundException in java?

Tags: java, maven, hbase

I am trying to run example from this particular site:
https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/tree/master/ch07

Now.. it compiles succesfully

But when I try to run an example, it gives me the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:113)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser
    at mapreduce.ParseJson2$ParseMapper.<init>(ParseJson2.java:48)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 13 more
```

Now from the pom in this file, I can see that simple json is included but I am not sure why is it throwing this issue.?

Comment: Are you using version 1.1 for json-simple ??

Comment: Please post the `pom.xml`.

Comment: @chrylis: The pom is posted in the link ? Can you please take a look there. Thanks

Comment: @Ankit: Yeah.. I mean i have the exact config.. if i am using maven to build the same project.. any chance i can screw that up?? Thanks

Comment: Ok, did you check the distribution file create after maven-install. Does it have the jason simple jar file ?

Comment: @Ankit: Yepp i can see the jar at /.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1

Comment: That is ok, but is it also present in your project's jar file which is generated under target folder(or lib folder) after running maven-install ? I am thinking that the json jar is not being packaged in your project's jar file. I had a look at the pom.xml and job.xml  in the link you provided and i think  <excludes><exclude>*.jar</exclude> </excludes> --- this line is the culprit in the job.xml. Can you confirm ?

Comment: No i dont see that json under my target folder.. ?? so should i comment that line  from my job.xml ??

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is that when run under map-reduce the jar you need is not in scope (i.e. not found). One way to fix that is to create a jar with all the dependencies and submit that as the job. Other options are to make sure it is available in each node and deploying the depdndecies to Hadoops' distribtued cache (but the first is the simplest - though it makes for slower job starts since the jar is bigger)